# implementation difference between ReLU and LeakyRelu

Tags: python, keras

I know those activations differ in their definition, however, when reading [ReLU's documentation](https://keras.io/activations/), it takes a parameter alpha as an input with 0 as default, and says

> **relu**
>
> relu(x, alpha=0.0, max_value=None) Rectified Linear Unit.
>
> Arguments
>
> **x**: Input tensor. alpha: Slope of the negative part. Defaults to zero.
>   max_value: Maximum value for the output. Returns
>
> The (leaky) rectified linear unit activation: x if x > 0, alpha * x if
>   x < 0. If max_value is defined, the result is truncated to this value.

And there is also a LeakyReLU with a [similar documentation](https://keras.io/layers/advanced-activations/), but as part of other module *(advanced activation)*

Is there a difference between them? and how shoud I import relu to instantiate it with alpha?

```
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU
..
..
model.add(Dense(512, 512, activation='linear')) 
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=.001)) # using Relu insted of LeakyRelu
```

Note that when using `LeakyReLU` I'm getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'LeakyReLU' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

but when I use ReLU instead, It works:

```
model.add(Activation('relu')) # This works correctly but can't set alpha
```

To sum up: What are de diferencies and how can I import ReLU to pass aplha to it?

Comment: Can you post the trace for the error? I can't reproduce it from the model snippet, LeakyReLU works properly.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't post the hole error because my goal was to underestand the difference between those implementations and I want to call ReLU with alpha parameter, even when I could call LeakyReLU because of the error (I mean, the error was a motivation to avoid using LeakyReLU). The error occurs when DeadReluDetector is used, but it can be a bug of this module (I should investigate more on this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as implementation is concerned they [call](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/315a80ae3cb65da2aa6308abd483f2f8643f1c8b/keras/layers/advanced_activations.py#L46) the same backend function `K.relu`. The difference is that `relu` is an activation function whereas LeakyReLU is a `Layer` defined under `keras.layers`. So the difference is how you use them. For activation *functions* you need to wrap around or use inside layers such `Activation` but LeakyReLU gives you a shortcut to that function with an alpha value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It's really clear, but How should I import/use ReLU to set alpha value?

Comment: Use LeakyReLU as a layer, it wraps the relu function for you. As I commented, I can't reproduce your error. Your usage is correct.

Comment: yes, the error is in another module (DeadReluDetector, from contrib) So I'm not sure where the error is, but at this moment I don't care, I just want to use ReLU while setting alpha value

Comment: Also note that when using the standard 'relu' activation in a dense layer or something, the alpha stays at 0 and is not 'trainable'/